# Set Covering: Find a set of arrays that overlap the elements of a target array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Let's say I have an array, `A` (sortable, if that helps)

I have a set of arrays, `B`, `C`, `D`, etc... (all sortable), all of which may partially or fully overlap array `A`.

I want to find the smallest set of arrays `B`, `C`, `D`, etc... that completely overlap array `A`. Returns first match.

eg,

```
const A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 'a', 'b', 'c'];

const B = [1, 3, 4, 5, 10];
const C = [1, 3, 5, 'a', 'b']
const D = [2, 4, 'a', 'b', 'c'];
const E = [1, 2, 'b', 'c'] 

findSmallestSet(A, [B, C, D, E]);
// => [B, D]
```

Aside: My original problem is finding node trees that fully overlap a target node tree, but I think the proposed problem above might be a simpler solution.

Comment: Smallest number of arrays B C D E or smallest combined number of elements in B C D E?

Comment: Smallest number of arrays. Thanks for clarifying question :)

Answer (score 2):

This is known as the 'Set Cover' problem. It's NP-complete, and well-studied. The 'right answer' depends on the size of the inputs and whether you can live with an approximation.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the Set Cover problem. Are there any restrictions that would greatly simplify the problem? Assume the number of sets is in the order of 10-100

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, first create sort function that will sort second parameter based on number of matching elements so you can start from there, then you loop each inner array and remove element from first parameter if its found it in current array and if there is left elements in first array you sort again keys and repeat that process using recursion.

```js
const A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 'a', 'b', 'c'];

const B = [1, 3, 4, 5, 10];
const C = [1, 3, 5, 'a', 'b']
const D = [2, 4, 'a', 'b', 'c'];
const E = [1, 2, 'b', 'c']

function findSmallestSet(one, [B, C, D, E]) {
  let obj = {B, C, D, E}
  let keys = Object.keys(obj);
  let getL = (e) => obj[e].filter(e => one.includes(e)).length
  let sortK = (keys) => keys.sort((a, b) => getL(b) - getL(a))
  sortK(keys)
  var r = []

  let find = (one, k) => {
    obj[k[0]].forEach(function(a) {
      var index = one.indexOf(a);
      if (index != -1) one.splice(index, 1)
    })
    
    r.push(k[0])

    if (one.length) {
      k.shift()
      sortK(k)
      find(one, k)
    }
  }

  find(one, keys)
  return r;
}

console.log(findSmallestSet(A, [B, C, D, E]));
```

Comment: I like the elegance of this solution but I think it fails for e.g. `const B = [1, 4, 5, 10, 'c']; const C = [3, 2, 'a', 'b']; const D = [2, 4, 'a', 'b', 'c']; const E = [5, 6, 'd', 'e'];`